# Adding row to binded datagridview

Tags: c#, datagrid, datagridview

I want to add a stored `CustomDataGridViewRow` into a `DataGridView` which is binded. Like follows:

```
CustomDataGridViewRow rowTemplate = new CustomDataGridViewRow();
dataGridView1.RowTemplate = rowTemplate;

Datenbank.cmd = 
    new SqlCommand("[Terminauswertung_Bericht_Gesamt]", Datenbank.connection);
Datenbank.cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
Datenbank.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@berichtsnr", 1);

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Datenbank.cmd);
dataSet1.Tables.Clear();
adapter.Fill(dataSet1, "Table");
bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dataSet1.Tables["Table"];
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

Thought it goes this way:

```
dataSet1.Tables[0].Rows.Add(Cache.getRow(1));

public class cache
{
    Dictionary<int, CustomDataGridViewRow> _cache = 
        new Dictionary<int, CustomDataGridViewRow>();

    public CustomDataGridViewRow getRow(int index)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, CustomDataGridViewRow> dic in _cache)
        {
            if (dic.Key == index)
                return (dic.Value);
        }
        return (new CustomDataGridViewRow());            
    }
}
```

But it only shows me DataGridViewRow { Index=1 } in first cell.

Comment: Would you mind posting your solution as an answer to your own question? (and accept it). It's perfectly OK to do that.

Comment: @GertArnold
ok, i do this in future, did not know that its ok because of this:

"Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 3 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."

 ill do it in 3 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it

```
DataRow newRow =test.Tables[0].NewRow();


newRow.ItemArray = Cache.getRowValues(child);
 test.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(newRow, c.Index+1);

 public string[] getRowValues(int index)
        {
            List<string> temp = new List<string>();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, CustomDataGridViewRow> dic in _cache)
            {
                if (dic.Key == index)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dic.Value.Cells)
                        temp.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
                }
            }
            string[] result = temp.ToArray();

            return (result);
        }
```